# Get the files of an directory in the web

Tags: java, url, directory

I have a homepage, which has a directory for downloads.
I want to read all files of this homepage automatically, from its directory.

For example I have the homepage: `www.homepage.org` and the subdirectory `resources/downloads` with the download files I want to show.

I have a Java Server with Spring and JSPs running and tried the following, which didn't work at all:

```
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    path += DOWNLOADS;
    URL url = null;
    String server = request.getServerName();
    try {
        url = new URL("https", server, request.getLocalPort(), path);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (url != null) {
        String externalForm = url.toExternalForm();
        File directory = new File(externalForm);
        String[] files = directory.list();
        for (String file : files) {
            ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to put the path to the files instead of the url. File is for a variety of operating systems not for url listing.

Comment: I tried it with `File directory = new File(path); File[] files = directory.listFiles();` as well, unfortunately, that didn't change anything! Still didn't work!

Comment: Can you quickly try this?
File directory = new File("/");
        String[] files = directory.list();
        for (String file : files) {
            System.out.println(file);
        }

Comment: That shows my Windows Directory (the computer I am working on).

Comment: Great! now remove "/" and put your absolute path to the folder you want to use to download. ex "c:\myserver\myapp\resources\download"
There is a nice example of a html filetree [here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree) with a JSP connector I hope this helps. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Servlet. If your resources directory is in your web app's root directory, then use

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/downloads");
File directory = new File(path);
if(directory.isDirectory()){
   String[] files = directory.list();
   for (String file : files) {
        writer.write(file + "<br/>");
   }
} else writer.write(directory.getAbsolutePath() + "could not be found");
```

Comment: Well this works. But will it work online. When I don't run the webserver on my computer, but access it online, after it has been deployed?

Comment: You are right, with one mistake:
getServletContext() is deprecated, if not used within a session (eg request). So it has to be `session.getServletContext().getRealPath()`

But that works just great.

Comment: It is not deprecated.    http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext()

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with using a FTP manager... 
You can view the code [here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/25538-JAVA-Code-for-Getting-List-of-Directories-and-its-SubDirectories-from-FTP-server.html)

I hope it will help you resolve the problem.

Comment: A FTP Manager would be a bit too much, since I am accessing my own server, just a directory of it and I only want to read the filename an provide a link!

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol does not provide a way to list the "files" in a "directory".  Indeed, from the perspective of the protocol spec, there is no such thing as a directory.

- If the webserver you are trying to access supports [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), you could use PROPFIND to find out a collection (i.e. directory)'s structure.
- Alternatively, if the webserver has directory listing enabled (and there is no `index.html` or whatever) then you could screen-scrape the listing HTML.
- Otherwise, there is no real solution ... using HTTP / HTTPS.

---

On rereading the question and the answers, it strikes me that the servlet that is trying to retrieve the directory listing and the servlet that hosts the directories *could actually be running on the same machine*.  In that case, you may have the option of accessing the information via the file system.  But this will entail the "client" servlet knowing how the "server" servlet represents things.  The URLs don't (and cannot) provide you that information.

The answer provided by rickz is one possible approach, though it only works if the client and server servlets are in fact the same servlet.

Comment: The server does not support directory listing. So screen scraping is no solution to it. The key is: I am accessing my own webserver. So I hoped there was an easy way to get the content of my own folder to show it as a list...

Comment: You must list all the files using your path to the files and then produce your own html to show it on web. ex. [link] (http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/)

Comment: And that is my problem: "You must list all the files using your path to the files"! I cannot list all the files using the file path, because the files are not shown! I can access them, but I cannot show them... or I just don't know how!

Comment: @DonMarco - if you can't get a directory listing, or you can't use WebDAV then **there is no real solution**.  Period.  You will have to find / implement an alternative way of getting the information that you require.

Answer (score 0):

You need to list the directory using the path to the directory not the url. Once you retrieve the files you must create your own html to put it your web if that's what you want.

There is a good example to create a directory listing and browsing with JQuery [here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree)

There is a JSP connector included in the package in the download section that you may need to tune up a bit if you don't want to use the JQuery tree.

good luck!

Comment: As the server does not support directory listings, I can't screen scrape the webpage for the files. I thought of that too, but that doesn't work!